# handling mysql constraint errors

Tags: mysql, constraints, unique-key

I tried searching for a solution in this website but I can't seem to find any.

I needed to find a way to know which field in my table is causing the constraint error.. In my table, say `members` table two fields (username,email) are unique keys and defined as unique keys apart from my primary key (memberid). When i add data to this table for a similar user and/or email address this error occurs:

"duplicate entry 'myemail@mail.com' for key2"

i want to tell the user which field is causing duplicate entry so as to say "that email is already registered"

I cannot seem to find a mysql function to loop through error keys upon insert...

Comment: This is why I don't usually like using constraints in MySQL. I mean, your app has to know about them, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

On my sites, I actually check the unique fields myself with Select 1 from tab where field = 'value' limit 1; just so that I can give nice error messages instead of encountering an exception coming back from my insert statement.

Answer (score 0):

i guess naming constraint fields is not yet a feature in mysql. hope they consider this as this is very useful and saves a lot of code times and lines.